# Is there anyway to customize start menu app appearance?

Tags: windows-10, modern-ui

I am loving the new windows start menu. However, I notice for many not native windows apps, they look very wierd in the start menu. Its like their icon, surrounded by a box of a solid color. Is there anyway to change this?

[image]

In the image above, my start menu as of now is pictured. I want to modify the icons of Illustrator, Dreamweaver, etc. to take up the full tile. Not sure if this is possible but it would be really nice.

Comment: Why can't you just right click on the icon and change the size of the icon?  There is also third-party software that further customize the start menu.

Comment: If you change the size of the tile, the box still remains. The entire thing just increases in size.

Comment: You can just fill it with new icons.

Comment: But how? Its not like I can just take a desktop icon, change it, and pin it. It looks normal as a desktop icon. Its when I pin it to start it looks weird.

Comment: Change the icon of a desktop icon, in the start menu, no that can't be done.  You cant change the size of the icon though.  I just did it on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tools to change the icons of desktop applications. One of them is [TileCreator](http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10/development/app-tilecreator-create-tiles-to-t3171167).

[image]

So the icon looks better:

[image]

On deviantart.com you can find such icons, like [those ones](http://dakirby309.deviantart.com/art/Metro-UI-Icon-Set-725-Icons-280724102).